# How would one change the Finder icon macOS Big Sur?

Tags: finder, dock

I'm trying to change the Finder icon, I went to

> /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/

I also have 2 icons ready to replace.

[image]

I tried to drag these 2 images up, I saw a block sign.

[image]

Then I was thinking, maybe it's locked, but then I don't have any options to unlock it.

[image]

How would one change the Finder icon?

I've also noticed, I also can't change Terminal, Message, Stickies, and Mail. :(

[image]

Comment: The System volume is sealed: it cannot be modified.

Comment: So we will never be able to modify our finder icon ?

Comment: Even if you _could_ change the icon, it is almost certain that it would be put back to the default after a macOS update.

Comment: I've also noticed, I also can't change Terminal, Message, Stickies, and Mail. :(

Comment: If you break the 'seal' the Mac will refuse to do anything except run a repair install. Not worth the effort.

Comment: MacOS provides very little in the way of user customisation of the interface.

Comment: @benwiggy Before Catalina, it was possible to make almost any customizations you want. Unfortunately OP jumped on the bandwagon a few years too late.

Comment: @At0mic "Almost any"? Perhaps. It's never been easy, not least since SIP was introduced. I dare say in Mavericks you could have had everything day-glo with flower petal icons and Corinthian column scroll bars, but the effort usually overwhelmed the desire.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
Starting with Big Sur, the System volume is sealed: it cannot be modified at all.